# how to unmarshall this xml using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How to unmarshal the below xml using JAXB and populate the java objects.

I am new to this JAXB. I need to populate java objects for multiple customers. I have two customer in customer list that needs to be converted to java object.

similarly for the services mentioned in the xml too...

```
   <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <customerList><customer><name>ATNT</name><category>Network</category>                               
        <country>USA</country><device>7600</device></customer>    
        <customer>
        <name>cisco</name>
        <category>Network</category>
        <country>USA</country>
        <device>ubr10k</device>    
      </customer>
     </customerList>
     <services>
      <softwareServices>
        <company>TCS</company>
        <country>India</country>
        <clients>
            <bank>SBI</bank>
            <insurance>LIC</insurance>
            <telecom>Ericsson</telecom>
        </clients>    
      </softwareServices>
      <softwareServices>
        <company>Infosys</company>
        <country>India</country>
        <clients>
            <bank>IDBI</bank>
            <insurance>Lombard</insurance>
            <telecom>Airtel</telecom>
        </clients>    
      </softwareServices>
     </services>
    </root>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? There are plenty of tutorials that should help you to get started

Comment: I tried to get unmarshal this xml and populate all customer objects from customerList  but i am getting null. suppose the xml is simple format like   contains single customer node able to get customer object                         <customer>
    <name>cisco</name>
    <category>Network</category>
    <country>USA</country>
    <device>ubr10k</device>    
  </customer>

Answer (score 0):

**1.** use the .xsd file (see code fragment **SO_customer.xsd** below)

**2.** execute xjc:

```
C:\dev\jdk1.6.0_41\bin\xjc -d src SO_customer.xsd
```

This will generate the java classes you need

**3.** unmarshall (see code fragment **MainClass.java** below).
This will output the name of the first customer: "ATNT"

**SO_customer.xsd** (from the xml you provided...) :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="customerList">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="customer" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="category"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="country"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="device"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="services">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="softwareServices" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="company"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="country"/>
                    <xs:element name="clients">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="bank"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="insurance"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="telecom"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**MainClass.java** :

```
package call;

import generated.Root;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

    public class MainClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {

                File file = new File("C:\\SO\\src\\input.xml");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                Root root = (Root) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(root.getCustomerList().getCustomer().get(0).getName());

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You welcome. Would you please validate the answer? Or give me one of those "fake internet points" I like by upvoting my answer? ;-)